# Preventing MySQL Queries in PHP while loops? (Use one instead)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Here are my tables...

```
Locations
__________________________________________________________
ID          Location           Region             Country

1           Newmarket          Ontario            Canada
2           Barrie             Ontario            Canada
3           New York City      New York           US
4           Buffalo            New York           US
5           Vancouver          British Columbia   Canada


Regions
__________________________________________________________
ID          Region               Country

1           Ontario              Canada
2           New York             US
3           British Columbia     Canada


Countries
__________________________________________________________
ID           Country

1            Canada
2            US
```

The tables are much bigger than this and I am trying to load the lists into an expandable list like so...

[image: List style]

The styling is no problem, I already have that sorted out. I am just attempting to load all this information in one fast MySQL Query. This is what I currently have in PHP and it takes a LOT of queries with these while loops. (With the size of my tables)

```
    <div id="listContainer">
        <ul id="expList">
                <?php
                $countries = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country ASC");
                while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($countries))
                {   
                    $cname = $crow['country'];
                    $regions = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM regions WHERE country = '$cname' ORDER BY region ASC")
                    ?>
                    <li class="country">
                    <?php echo $cname; ?>
                        <ul class="undercountry">
                                <?php
                                while($rrow = mysqli_fetch_array($regions))
                                {
                                echo "<li>";
                                $rname = $rrow['region'];
                                echo $rname;
                                ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php
                                        $locations = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE region = '$rname' AND country = '$cname' ORDER BY location ASC");
                                        while($lrow = mysqli_fetch_array($locations)){
                                            $lname = $lrow['location'];
                                            echo $lname;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php
                                echo "</li>";
                                }
                                ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to do this? It's okay to only use the locations table and group but I'm not too good at writing select queries.

Comment: You already have the country and region in your locations table. Why don't you just use the one table, instead of the redundant information in your other tables?

Comment: I know it seems strange to have the tables like that, but I need them for other uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your locations table has all the information of country and regions as well, you don't need to use the other tables. You can run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY country, region
```

This will return you an array sorted by country, and then region. You can then loop over this to create your `select` element. Here's an example that prints out the results as you need. Modify it as needed:

```
<?php

// example results
$results = array(
    array(
        'Location' => 'Vancouver',
        'Region' => 'British Columbia',
        'Country' => 'Canada'
    ),
    array(
        'Location' => 'New Market',
        'Region' => 'Ontario',
        'Country' => 'Canada'
    ),
    array(
        'Location' => 'Barrie',
        'Region' => 'Ontario',
        'Country' => 'Canada'
    ),
    array(
        'Location' => 'New York City',
        'Region' => 'New York',
        'Country' => 'US'
    )
);

$i = 0;

while ($i < count($results)) {
    $currentCountry = $results[$i]['Country'];
    echo "-" . $currentCountry . PHP_EOL;

    while ($results[$i]['Country'] == $currentCountry) {
        $currentRegion = $results[$i]['Region'];
        echo "--" . $currentRegion . PHP_EOL;

        while ($results[$i]['Region'] == $currentRegion) {
            echo "---" . $results[$i]['Location'] . PHP_EOL;
            $i++;
            if ($i == count($results)) break;
        }

        if ($i == count($results)) break;       
    }   
}
```

This way you only need to run a single SQL query.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/6i6wWMNI)

Answer (score -1):

You can combine all tables in a join, then run the query only once and loop through all the rows. In the loop, keep track of a comparison value to check if the country, region or location have changed and select and style the output accordingly.

```
select * from locations l, regions r, countries c
where r.country = c.country and l.region = r.region
order by c.country, r.region, l.location
```